# Yii 2 Active Record nested many to many relations

Tags: php, activerecord, yii, many-to-many, subquery

I have 4 table products, properties, property_items, property_product with relations like this 
Product has many properties.
Property has many property_items.
Product has many property_items.
Property_product is intermediary table.

```
-- products --
Id   name
1   Arrabiata
2   Bolognese

--properties --
Id   name
1   Pasta type
2   Size

-- property_items --
Id   name                   value      property_id
1    Spinach spaghetti      .....      1
2    Linguine               .....      1
3    Spaghetti              .....      1
4    Small                  ....       2
5    Medium                 ....       2
6    Large                  ...        2

-- property_product  -- 
product_id    property_id  property_item_id
    1             1              1
    1             1              2
    1             2              4
    1             2              6
    2             1              2
    2             1              3
    2             2              5
```

I try use Gii to create those models with relations .

```
class Products extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
    //code
    ....

    public function getProperties()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Properties::className(), ['id' => 'property_id'])
                    ->viaTable('property_product', ['product_id' => 'id']);
    }
}

class Properties extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
  //code
  ...

  public function getPropertyItems()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(PropertyItems::className(), ['property_id' => 'id']);
    }
}
```

I want to query data with multi nested relation.
How can i create json response with below format in one active record query ?

```
[
{
    "id": "1",
    "name": "Arrabiata",
    "properties": [
        {
            "id": "1",
            "name": "Pasta type",
            "property_items" : [
                {
                    "id": "1",
                    "name": "Spinach spaghetti",
                },
                {
                    "id": "2",
                    "name": "Linguine",
                },
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": "2",
            "name": "Size",
            "property_items" : [
                {
                    "id": "4",
                    "name": "Small",
                },
                {
                    "id": "6",
                    "name": "Large",
                },
            ]
        },
    ],
},
{
    "id": "2",
    "name": "Bolognese",
    "properties": [
        {
            "id": "1",
            "name": "Pasta type",
            "property_items" : [
                {
                    "id": "2",
                    "name": "Linguine",
                },
                {
                    "id": "3",
                    "name": "Spaghetti",
                },
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": "2",
            "name": "Size",
            "property_items" : [
                {
                    "id": "5",
                    "name": "Medium",
                },
            ]
        },
    ]
}]
```

I use this query but it took too much perfomance

```
Menus::find()->with(['products' => function ($query) {
            $query->with(['properties']);
        }])
        ->where(['>', 'status', 0])
        ->andWhere(['resid' => $id])->asArray()->all();;
        foreach ($menus as &$menu) {
            foreach ($menu['products'] as &$product) {
                foreach ($product['properties'] as &$property) {
                    $propertyItems = PropertyItems::find()->where(['property_id' => $property['id']]
                    )
                    ->leftJoin('property_product', 'property_items.id = property_product.property_item_id')
                    ->where(['property_product.product_id' => $product['id'],
                             'property_product.property_id' => $property['id']])
                    ->asArray()->all();
                    $property['propertyItems'] = $propertyItems;
                }
            }
        }
```

If I use this query

```
Menus::find()->with(['products' => function ($query) {
                                        $query->with(['properties' => function ($query) {
                                            $query->with(['propertyItems']);
                                        }
                                        ]);
                                    }
                          ])->asArray()->all();
```

But the result not same as i expected because all property_items will show up in properties instead of depend on relating with products via table "property_product"

```
[
{
    "id": "1",
    "name": "Arrabiata",
    "properties": [
        {
            "id": "1",
            "name": "Pasta type",
            "property_items" : [
                {
                    "id": "1",
                    "name": "Spinach spaghetti",
                },
                {
                    "id": "2",
                    "name": "Linguine",
                },
                {
                    "id": "3",
                    "name": "Spaghetti",
                },
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": "2",
            "name": "Size",
            "property_items" : [
                {
                    "id": "4",
                    "name": "Small",
                },
                {
                    "id": "6",
                    "name": "Large",
                },
                {
                    "id": "5",
                    "name": "Medium",
                },
            ]
        },
    ],
},
{
    "id": "2",
    "name": "Bolognese",
    "properties": [
        {
            "id": "1",
            "name": "Pasta type",
            "property_items" : [
                {
                    "id": "1",
                    "name": "Spinach spaghetti",
                },
                {
                    "id": "2",
                    "name": "Linguine",
                },
                {
                    "id": "3",
                    "name": "Spaghetti",
                },
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": "2",
            "name": "Size",
            "property_items" : [
                {
                    "id": "4",
                    "name": "Small",
                },
                {
                    "id": "6",
                    "name": "Large",
                },
                {
                    "id": "5",
                    "name": "Medium",
                },
            ]
        }
    ]
}]
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You have to override the function `fields()` of the `Products` and `Properties` models.

for example:

```
class Products extends ActiveRecord {

 function fields(){
    return ['properties'];
   }
 }


class Properties extends ActiveRecord {

     function fields(){
        return ['property_items'];
     }
 }
```

Comment: I already added more details for my question. Thanks for helping me